# Magento - addOrderedQty multiple dates

Tags: mysql, magento, collections, product

In order to get a product collection with "ordered qty" for last 30 days this code will work:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty(date("Y-m-d",(time()-(60*60*24*30))), date("Y-m-d",time()))
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','name','price','cost'))
        ->joinField('qty',
                             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                             'qty',
                             'product_id=entity_id',
                             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                             'left');
                             ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

If using only `->addOrderedQty()` the result will be for life time sales.

But how to get data for life time AND last 30 days in same collection?

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->addOrderedQty($from, $to);
```

where, `$from` is the beginning of your data range (2018-06-19)
and `$to` is the end of your date rage or today. (2018-07-19

Comment: Please offer an explanation for your answer. Formatting your code will also help everyone understand better too.